# override prepareOnStartup method in GenericFileProcessStrategy class

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm using apache camel File in order to read a file from the file system into a bean method. I'm using it with spring xml . I need to override prepareOnStartup method in GenericFileProcessStrategy class on the route process .
Can you please tell me what is the Syntax to do it in the from uri route line in the spring xml file ?

the spring xml :

```
<bean id="adoFilter" class="calypsox.bllInterfaces.cashMgn.cashMgnAdo.AdoFileFilter"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="cashMgn">

  <propertyPlaceholder id="cashMgnProperty" 
     location="${bll.resources.env}/cashMgn.properties" />

  <route id="cashMgnAdo">
      <from uri="file:{{cashMgnAdoFileDir}}?filter=#adoFilter;move=.org/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockCheckInterval=2000&amp;readLockTimeout=10000&amp;moveFailed=.failed" />
       <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
       <to uri="bean:cashMgnHandler?method=handleCashMgnAdo" />
  </route>

</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GenericFileProcessStrategy` can be set with the `processStrategy` property :

```
<bean id="myProcessStrategy" class="..."/>

..

<from uri="file:..?..processStrategy=#myProcessStrategy"/>
```